# Laravel router to controller transfer variable solution needed

Tags: php, laravel

php subdomain and call a function and also send varible to function in controller.
its working fine but i face problem on default domain becuase on our default domain we have no language prefix. like this

```
Route::domain('{keyword}.{lang}.laravel.test')->group(function () { Route::get("/{keywords}", 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@getapp'); });
```

```
    public function app($keyword, $lang, $keywords)
    {
}
```

it show like this subdomain

```
https://keyword.fr.laravel.test/keywords
```

its fine but i now need to handle our deafult url on same function but without $lang tansfer to its not working please tell me how to handle this type of url without langauge prefix

```
https://keyword.laravel.test/keywords
```

Comment: Because having a httpS on every subdomain is more expensive, you should sincerely consider using : `mcamara/laravel-localization` and url like `domain.ext\fr` & `domain.ext` for the base language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your code to handle both subdomains plus the default domain without the language prefix.

```
Route::domain('{keyword}.{lang}.laravel.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get("/{keywords}", 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@app');
});

Route::domain('{keyword}.laravel.test')->group(function () {
    Route::get("/{keywords}", 'App\Http\Controllers\SiteController@app');
});

public function app($keyword, $keywords, $lang = null)
{
    // Controller logic goes here..
}
```

Comment: can you help me how out how to set our base url to subdomain as lang subdomain like en.laravel.test becuase on our app url when i open this url https://keyword.fr.laravel.test/keywords its working fine but our <html lang="es"> show default lang